# how to export a default function and default object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, amd, commonjs, module.exports

I would like to export as a default object and a default function such that I can use as:

```js
const config = require('./config')

const url = config.url
```

**AND**

```js
const config = require('./config')

const url = config({url: 'uniqueurl'}).url
```

I imagine I need to use `module.exports = { default: config }` but how do I also add a `default` function?

Comment: That's CommonJS, not ES5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`module.exports` is the *single value that you export*.

If you want to export a function, then export a function.

If you want that function to have properties, then add them as you would to any other object. Functions are objects.

```
function myFunction (url) {
    return { url: url };
}

myFunction.url = "something";

module.exports = myFunction;
```

Comment: I have a large config map, is there a non-cumbersome way to do that?

Comment: Iterate over it and assign each property in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one default export!

What you *can* do, is attach properties to the function, because this is JavaScript and of course it is possible!

```
function config(options) {
    // 'yer code
}

config.url = "https://example.com";

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, is there a non-cumbersome way to do this for a large config map? just asked Quentin as well

Comment: You can iterate your actual config object and copy the properties over to your function.